# Unable to insert data into database using LINQ WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq-to-sql

While working on my project I encountered many problems related to database and connectionstring which I solved (I think). While solving those I got stuck on weird stuff that is unsolvable to me.

I can't save data to my database unless my database is empty so basicly my program adds data once then it stops working.

When i created my database I'd chosen Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)
Database was created via Server Explorer in Visual studio 2019.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [Id]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [log]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [pass] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

It is connected to my app by LINQ instance. My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WpfApp2.Properties.Settings.projectDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\USER\source\repos\WpfApp2\projectDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This connection string was edited in my app.config and Settings.settings.

My code is simple but Im trying how to solve this problem so I just wanna understand how it works and what to do to fix it.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   using(DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext())
    {
        Table tab = new Table();
        tab.log = txb1.Text;
        tab.pass = txb2.Text;
        db.Tables.InsertOnSubmit(tab);
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Dodano");
            txb1.Text = "";
            txb2.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie dodano");
        }
    }

}
```

Yes my program has only 1 function to read and insert stuff from textboxes to my database.

my xaml code looks like 2 textboxes and button which is supposed to add data into database

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="226,97,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="226,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" RenderTransformOrigin="0.482,3.304"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would be really thankful if anyone can tell me how to solve it. If this problem was solved somewhere then Im sorry for posting once more but i couldn't find anything related to that.

Thanks in advance for your help and have a  nice day!

@edit
I wanna mention this problem only happens to me when doing WPF projects

Comment: Are you getting an Exception?  Add the details.

Comment: Don't catch and swallow the exception.  It's there to tell you why it failed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I removed try catch part and it still doesn't work. There's no error, nothing. It just doesn't add data if there is anything in database

Comment: @ASh Thnaks. I've done that already and it didn't change anything at all. Still doesn't add data

Comment: The Id column is not specified, you can set it to `identity(1,1)` so you don't need to specify it in the code.

Comment: I almost solved my problem. There was some error with connectionstring. After changing it to Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\USER\Desktop\portiEXzDB\portiEXzDB\portiEXzDB\portiEX\PortiEXDBs.mdf;Integrated Security=True                                   Im able to insert data and work on it however i please but there's another error. Whenever i wanna use universal path for my connectionstring there's error or it doesn't save into my database.